# how to transfer onClick code from XML to Kotlin for recyclerview with data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, data-binding

Below code is the XML for the recyclerview item.

How to transfer **android:onClick="@{() -> sumListener.onClick(sum)}"**(last line) from XML to kotlin?

I would like to make a onLongClick, but XML has no onLongClick.

Please let me know if need more info.

```
    <data>

        <variable
            name="sum"
            type="com.cementcaibird.astock.database.Sum" />

        <variable
            name="sumListener"
            type="com.cementcaibird.astock.main.SumListener" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ll_item_container"
        android:onClick="@{() -> sumListener.onClick(sum)}">

        ...(other view code)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved with this method

```
 <data>

        <variable
            name="sum"
            type="com.cementcaibird.astock.database.Sum" />

        <variable
            name="sumListener"
            type="com.cementcaibird.astock.main.SumListener" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ll_item_container">

        ...(other view code)
```

In your Activity/Fragment

```
private lateinit var binding: YourBindingclass
..

binding.linearLayout.setOnClickListener { view-> 
    // Handle your click here
}

binding.linearLayout.setOnLongClickListener{ view-> 
    // Handle your long click here
    true
}
```